# Attribute Routing related issue using Asp.Net MVC 5 and Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to change my existing web api controller from convention based routing to attribute routing, so I changed my existing code to the following:

```
[Route("api/Visitors")]
public IQueryable<Visitor> GetVisitors()
        {
            return db.Visitors;
        }
```

and GET method works great, but when I am applying same attribute to POST method like:

```
[Route("api/Visitors")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(Visitor))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostVisitor(Visitor visitor)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Visitors.Add(visitor);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = visitor.Id }, visitor);
        }
```

It is throwing following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

at this line `resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` of the following method:

```
 public bool SaveVisitor(Visitor visitor)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp =  client.PostAsJsonAsync<Visitor>("/api/Visitors", visitor).Result;
            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

`client` is an instance of `HttpClient` at class level.
I am not able to get the reason behind this exception. What am I missing here? If I remove attribute routing data is saved/retrieved as expected. I am referring to the article on [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the **[HttpPost]** attribute to your "Post" endpoint. As follows:

```
        [Route("api/Visitors")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(Visitor))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostVisitor(Visitor visitor)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Visitors.Add(visitor);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = visitor.Id }, visitor);
        }
```

Another possibility... it seems from your code that your controller class might be called "VisitorsController". Visitors being plural.

Maybe try to add an 's' to your post method?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostVisitors(Visitor visitor)
```

Comment: I have already tried both options you suggested but to no avail :(